# Points that do not fall into Polygons

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. Both with Geometry column. Table1 is Points and Table2 is Polygons.

I have to select all points that do not fall into some of polygons. Have no idea how to do that in SQL Server...

Answer (score 0):

From your description this sounds like mostly the point in polygon problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon.

My guess is that you would select a polygon from your polygon table, and then check all of the points to see if they fall within that polygon. Hope this helps. I'm pretty sure there's no query that looks like

SELECT * from POINTS where POINTS.geo INSIDE polygon.geo

;)